# Error Accessing External Database for Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm trying to display database contents from a DB on my server to an android app.

I am stuck with errors below, some guidance would be great.

```
public class TestExternalDatabaseActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView resultView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  // StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED
   resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    getData(); 
}

public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.url.co.uk/php/getAllCustomers.php"); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
}
catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
}
//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
      }
catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
  }

    //parse json data
    try {
   String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       s = s + 


               "Pos : "+json.getString("Pos")+"   "+json.getString("ErrorMessage")+"\n"+
               "Name : "+json.getString("Name")+"\n"+
               "Total : "+json.getString("Total")+"\n\n";
   }

   resultView.setText(s);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
  }

}

}
```

**Here is my php file:**

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxx");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
mysql_select_db("player", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scores");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $output[]=$row;
} 

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

**Here is DB :**

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pos        | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| errorthing | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total      | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |  
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Data in Player Database - Score Table:**

| **pos** | **errorthing** | **name** | **total** 
| -- | javascript:void(0); | Scott | -- | | -- | javascript:void(0); | Billy | -- | 
| -- | javascript:void(0); | Jon | -- | | -- | javascript:void(0); | Bill | -- | 
| -- | javascript:void(0); | Tim | -- |

**Error with STRICT MODE DISABLED**

07-09 05:34:52.091: E/log_tag(785): **Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**
07-09 05:34:52.101: E/log_tag(785): **Error  converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null**
07-09 05:34:52.101: E/log_tag(785): **Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of**

**Error with STRICT MODE ENABLED**

07-09 05:51:01.582: E/log_tag(816): **Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**
07-09 05:51:01.582: E/log_tag(816): Error  converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
07-09 05:51:01.612: E/log_tag(816): **Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of** 
07-09 05:51:02.643: D/gralloc_goldfish(816): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-09 05:52:36.942: D/dalvikvm(864): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 258K, 14% free 2759K/3208K, paused 25ms, total 27ms
07-09 05:52:37.813: D/dalvikvm(864): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 432K, 19% free 2839K/3464K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
07-09 05:52:37.892: E/log_tag(864): Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value

07-09 05:21:19.109: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 265K, 15% free 2752K/3208K, paused 36ms, total 38ms
07-09 05:21:19.889: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 427K, 18% free 2837K/3456K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
07-09 05:21:19.989: E/log_tag(786): Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value (RandomAccessFile.java:118)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:150)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsBytes(IoUtils.java:116)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:110)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.CertPinManager.readPinFile(CertPinManager.java:112)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.CertPinManager.rebuild(CertPinManager.java:86)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.CertPinManager.(CertPinManager.java:50)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.(TrustManagerImpl.java:137)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.(TrustManagerImpl.java:97)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineGetTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:80)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactory.java:219)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.createDefaultTrustManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:402)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:393)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.(SSLParametersImpl.java:119)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.getDefault(SSLParametersImpl.java:147)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:34)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:56)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection$NoPreloadHolder.(HttpsURLConnection.java:114)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:163)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.(SSLSocketFactory.java:247)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.(SSLSocketFactory.java:139)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory$NoPreloadHolder.(SSLSocketFactory.java:162)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:170)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(DefaultHttpClient.java:177)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:221)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:539)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.getData(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:42)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.onCreate(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:33)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 05:21:20.019: D/StrictMode(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=889 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1139)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.getData(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:42)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.onCreate(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:33)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 05:21:20.029: D/StrictMode(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=837 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1139)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.getData(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:42)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.onCreate(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:33)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=783 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1139)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.getData(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:42)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.onCreate(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:33)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 05:21:20.039: D/StrictMode(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=183 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1139)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:390)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.getData(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:55)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.onCreate(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:33)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 05:21:20.049: D/StrictMode(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 05:21:20.269: D/gralloc_goldfish(786): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

**Data in Player Database - Score Table:**

+------+---------------------+---------------------------+-------+
| pos  | errorthing          | name                      | total |
+------+---------------------+---------------------------+-------+
| --   | javascript:void(0); | Scott                     | --    |
| --   | javascript:void(0); | Billy                     | --    |
| --   | javascript:void(0); | Jon                       | --    |
| --   | javascript:void(0); | Bill                      | --    |
| --   | javascript:void(0); | Tim                       | --    |

Answer (score 0):

You were following my video on YouTube.

First I need to know full error message after you enabled strict
Mode.

Looking at code you have provided above, you are using wrong keys of JSON object. 
You have key "errorthing" in your db and you are looking for "ErrorMessage" in your code. Plus keys are case-sensitive so look for exact keys and not make first letter capital.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my question above with Full Error and Data from my database. Also note I changed ErrorMessage to errorthing but still getting error

Comment: The error says that your php response is either null or not valid JSON. So can you copy the url you are using and paste it in browser and let me know what is response there ??

Comment: There never seems to be a response there. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Where is your php script stored??  Your url seems to be pointing to some hosted site. In that case your MySQL credentials are wrong.

Comment: I have a cloud hosting server, I have configured it with ubuntu and i setup a MySQL database on the server. I installed apache so I could point to a php on my server via URL. (I noticed you use a URL to point to the php in the sample code) so thats why i dropped my php at location healthytowns.co.uk/php/getAllCustomers.php.

Sorry Im new to this, I'm very confused.

Comment: I thought since my domains are hosted on the same server, calling localhost in the php file would be ok, since the databases are all on the same server

Comment: Hope you got the answer. Your web hosting will provide you MySQL credentials. You can close the question here and accept answer. Thanks

Comment: I got it working thanks very much Taseen :) now to figure out to display content in list view :)